# Unable to figure out what's wrong. how to debug

Tags: node.js, mongodb, angular, crud

```
module.js:471
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module '..models/article'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:469:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:417:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Sankalp Singhai\blogapp\server\routes\api.js
:4:17)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Sankalp Singhai\blogapp\server.js:7:13)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
```

Where to look for module folder? Is the error in database connectivity. Created the database on mlab.

Answer (score 0):

```
    const express = require('express');
    const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
    const path = require('path');
    const http = require('http');
    const app = express();

    const api = require('./server/routes/api');
    //parsers
    app.use(bodyParser.json());
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended : false}));

    app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname,'dist')));

    app.use('/api' , api)

    app.get('*', (req,res)=>{
        res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'dist/index.html'));
    });

    //set port
    const port = process.env.PORT || '3000';
    app.set('port' , port);

    const server = http.createServer(app);

    server.listen(port, () => console.log('Running on localhost: ${port}'));

**server.js**
```

Answer (score -1):

```
C:\Users\Sankalp Singhai\blogapp>node server.js
(node:4068) DeprecationWarning: `open()` is deprecated in mongoose >= 4.11.0, us
e `openUri()` instead, or set the `useMongoClient` option if using `connect()` o
r `createConnection()`. See http://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html#use-mong
o-client
Running on localhost: ${port}
Error connecting
(node:4068) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejec
tion id: 1): MongoError: failed to connect to server [6:27017] on first connect
[MongoError: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND 6 6:27017]
```

**Error connecting**

Comment: To use template strings, you need to use back-ticks "`". It looks like you're using `${port}` without that. 

Also, please refrain from counter-questioning. You can start a new issue if you want, or post it as a comment. Before we actually see your code, we can't debug this issue.

Comment: Is your Mongo instance running? If it is, where is the configuration? How are you connecting to the database? The line `MongoError` should tell you that it has nothing to do with your `server.js` file; check your Mongo configuration. 

Also, change `'Running on localhost: ${port}'` to `\`Running on localhost: ${port}\``

Comment: All Done! Thanks for the help.